# jldoctest blocks in julia docstrings included in documentation but tests not run on them

Tags: automated-tests, julia, docstring

I'm learning Julia and I'm trying to include doctests in the doctrings of functions in the form of [REPL examples](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/doctests/#REPL-Examples-1)

I can't get those doctests to be run: nothing happens when I include errors in the expected output.

Tests for jldoctest blocs in the markdown source are run.

Here is my testing setup:

```
$ tree DocTests/
DocTests/
├── docs
│   ├── make.jl
│   └── src
│       ├── index.md
└── src
    └── DocTests.jl

6 directories, 13 files
```

With the following `DocTests/src/DocTests.jl` module content:

````
module DocTests

export test

"""
    test(x)

```jldoctest
julia> test(2)
4
```
"""
test(x) = x+1

end
````

The following `DocTests/docs/make.jl` documentation building instructions:

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "../src/")
using Documenter, DocTests

makedocs(sitename="Testing doctests",
    doctest = true,
)
```

And the following `DocTests/docs/src/index.md` markdown source:

````
 ```@autodocs
Modules = [DocTests]
```

### Just testing jldoctests

```@meta
DocTestSetup = quote
    using DocTests
end
```

```jldoctest
julia> test(2)
5
```

```@meta
DocTestSetup = nothing
```
````

And this is what happens when I build the documentation:

````
$ cd DocTests/docs/
$ julia make.jl
[ Info: SetupBuildDirectory: setting up build directory.
[ Info: Doctest: running doctests.
┌ Error: doctest failure in src/index.md:14-17
│ 
│ ```jldoctest
│ julia> test(2)
│ 5
│ ```
│ 
│ Subexpression:
│ 
│ test(2)
│ 
│ Evaluated output:
│ 
│ 3
│ 
│ Expected output:
│ 
│ 5
│ 
│   diff =
│    Warning: Diff output requires color.
│    53
└ @ Documenter.DocTests ~/.julia/packages/Documenter/zbb48/src/DocTests.jl:364
[ Info: ExpandTemplates: expanding markdown templates.
[ Info: CrossReferences: building cross-references.
[ Info: CheckDocument: running document checks.
[ Info: Populate: populating indices.
[ Info: RenderDocument: rendering document.
[ Info: HTMLWriter: rendering HTML pages.
````

As you can see, only the test in the markdown source is run (expected output `5`), not the one in the function docstring (expected output `4`).

Loading `build/index.html` in my browser shows that de documentation for the function has been built. In particular, the html file contains this piece of code:

`<div><pre><code class="language-julia">test(x)</code></pre><pre><code class="language-julia-repl">julia&gt; test(2)
4</code></pre></div>`

What's wrong with my setup?

I'm using Julia version 1.1.1:

```
$ julia --version
julia version 1.1.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that doctests contained in docstrings are only run if the module containing the docstrings is specified in the `makedocs` call.

Amending the file `DocTests/docs/make.jl` as follows should cause the doctest to fail as desired:

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "../src/")
using Documenter, DocTests

DocMeta.setdocmeta!(DocTests, :DocTestSetup, :(using DocTests); recursive=true)

makedocs(
    sitename = "Testing doctests",
    modules  = [DocTests],
    doctest  = true,
)
```

Note that `using DocTests` has to be called inside the sandboxes used for evaluating the doctests. The call in the `@meta` block in the file `DocTests/docs/src/index.md` only brings DocTests into scope for doctests in this file. The scope for doctests in docstrings of the DocTests module is not affected, hence the additional call `DocMeta.setdocmeta!` in the listing above is required, see the [Documenter.jl documentation](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/doctests/#Module-level-metadata).